# Place url image on top of black background color html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm currently creating a site where I would like to place images hosted on imgur on top of a black background using html/css/sinatra. I have attempted to use z-index for each element, but cannot get the image to be *on top* of the black background (it is stuck behind the black background). It is a random generated quote website. The code is as follows.

```
<body background="cartier.jpg">
<div class="container">

<script language="JavaScript" id="quote">
var Quotation=new Array()
Quotation[0] = "insert quote here";
Quotation[1] = "insert quote here";
Quotation[2] = "insert quote here";

var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();

</script><br><br>

</div>
<div class="button" type="text/css">
  <a href="." STYLE="text-decoration: none">GIVE ME MORE GUIS</a>
</div>
<!-- <div class="picture" style="background-image: url(<%= randomized_background_image %>;">)>
</div> -->
<style type="text/css" class="image">
  html {
    background: url(<%= randomized_background_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  }
</style>
```

```
.container {
  /*margin: 20px auto;*/
  /*z-index: 3;*/
  width: 500px;
  height: 505px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  /*border: 1px dotted black;*/
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#quote {
  z-index: 2;
}

/*.picture {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin-top: -640px;
  margin-left: 430px;
  border: 1px dotted white;
/*  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/armyxnE.png")
*/

.image {
  z-index: 1;
}

style {
 z-index: 1;
}

html {
  z-index: 1;
}

.button {
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width: 389px;
   height: 46px;
   line-height: 46px;
   vertical-align: text-middle;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fffaff;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 35px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
   text-shadow: none;
}
.button > span {
   display: -moz-inline-block;
   margin: auto 0;
}


a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: auto 0;
}


body {
  /*position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;*/
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
```

### }

and in my helpers....

```
def randomized_background_image
  images = ["http://i.imgur.com/armyxnE.png", "http://i.imgur.com/DJF4CoC.png"]
  images[rand(images.size)]
```

### end

Someone please help!!!!

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but your question is terribly written. I would suggest at least providing a JSFiddle to help answerers check out your code and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding z-index:-1 to your background?

```
 background{
 position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble understanding what you're trying to do - but are you saying that you want to set the background of the whole page to black, with the imgur image overlaid on that?  If so, this may be what you want.

Instead of:

```
html {
    background: url(<%= randomized_background_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Put:

```
body {
    background: #000 url(<%= randomized_background_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

The `#000` sets the colour to black, so that any background showing behind the image (in the case of an image with transparency for example) will appear black.